# JavaScript code to display plain PDF file

Tags: javascript, pdf

Is there a JavaScript code available somewhere that could display a very simple PDF file? I know there's [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), but that's a big source code coming with a lot of capabilities. I just want to be able to see the plain file, no need for fancy stuff like hyperlinks.

Comment: Couldn't you just add an `<iframe>` to the page and set its `src` attribute to the PDF's URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/) if you don't want to have to work around those annoying browser quirks. Its only about 1.8 KB and doesn't depend on any other JS frameworks.

Comment: PDFObject depends on the PDF reader attached to the browser. I would like something that's not dependent on an existing reader.